# Catch exit value from a script in a script

Tags: bash

I try to catch a return value from a executed script in an other bash script

My first file: script1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 22
```

My second script:

```
#!/bin/bash
./script1.sh
return_value=$?
echo "$return_value"
```

My value seems to be empty.

Edit: I use the script1.sh into a dpkg postinst script and it seems into the dpkg that the return value is not catch

Comment: script2.sh returns 22 for me.

Comment: Indeed, I edit my post to explain more properly. The problem happens in a dpkg postinst script.

Comment: "a dpkg postinst script" doesn't sound like Ubuntu ... what OS are you working on?

Comment: Learn to ask about your real problem, problem X, instead of about problem Y, which you think is the solution to the problem. More chance to get the good help, and suggestions you may not have though about.

Comment: @Raffa why wouldn't one write dpkg postinit scripts on Ubuntu? They are just used for packaging `.deb` packages, which Ubuntu most definitely uses.

Comment: @Esther True but, the packaging process ought to be release/version specific and such a general question can’t be squarely answered in the absence of such important information … It’s also not the kind of question that you’d expect from an average Ubuntu user given the abundance and diversity of packages available from the official repositories … I mean how would one answer such a vague question? … Now you might agree with me it’s not a normal packaging question nor it denotes an issue related to Ubuntu that can be solved IMHO :-)

Comment: if you want dpkg to catch the return value, then I assume that, like other shell scripts, you have to return that value *from the postinst script*. Otherwise, the script's return value by default is the return value of the last command it ran, which in this case is `echo` which should run successfully.